# PHP check if Ghostscript is installed on server

Tags: php, pdf-generation, ghostscript

I have a PHP script that uses Ghostscript on my CentOS machine using following command:

```
gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=$outputName
```

I know that ghostscript is installed, but would like my PHP script to be able to detect if it is and if not display error saying required Ghostscript not installed.

Any ideas how I can do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you check if `gs` is in the path of whatever shell PHP's using? Perhaps you need an absolute path, e.g. `/usr/bin/gs` instead.

Answer (score 5):

Use the shell. You can use the `which` command, e.g.

```
system( "which gs > /dev/null", $retval );
if ( $retval == 0 ) {
    // run gs
}
```

You can also check the version:

```
if (shell_exec("gs --version") >= $min_gs_version) {
    // run gs
}
```

(Note that I wrote this here inline and never tested, so there may be syntax errors

Comment: Yes, there is a syntax error, you put '$' sign with the function name, I replaced $shell_exec with shell_exec, and it worked fine for me

Comment: fixed. Thanks @ShehrozAhmed